# how to vary layout size based on different screen sizes in android?

Tags: android

I used sp for text font size and dp for everything else, but still when i run my app on small screen size phone the image and text on my first page goes below screen and is partially visible...plz provide me some help in figuring out what should i change in below code..i am a beginner

This is my xml file for displaying image and some text below it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="120dp" >

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/welcome" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/mats"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml for listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ListActivity"

 >  


 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    >
    </ListView>
   <TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/textItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `android:background` instead of `android:src`. The image will stretch to fill

Comment: try researching a bit more.there are numerous blogs and articles on this topic.Its probably the most asked question by beginners

Answer (score -1):

Use specified directories for layout and values for different screen size.
Look here:
[Screen size](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)